# Parse html list with javascript then output drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some javascript that will automatically take text in a html ul list and then output it as a drop down.  Here is what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/KRWHP/

The problem of course is that the code doesnt go through each list item and output it in its own option tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("li").each(function () {
    $('<option />').text($(this).text())
                   .val($(this).text())
                   .appendTo("select");    
});
```

[Your fiddle, re-fiddlified.](http://jsfiddle.net/KRWHP/4)

Comment: B CUZ U alrdy optmiz 4 me. KTHXBYE. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need jQuery. Just create a new option node for each element and append that to the select.

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];

[].forEach.call(ul.children, function (el) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = el.textContent; 
    select.appendChild(option);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KRWHP/3/)